# Python Parse JSON array

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I'm trying to put together a small python script that can parse out array's out of a large data set. I'm looking to pull a few `key:values` from each object so that I can play with them later on in the script. Here's my code:

```py
# Load up JSON Function
import json

# Open our JSON file and load it into python
input_file = open ('stores-small.json')
json_array = json.load(input_file)

# Create a variable that will take JSON and put it into a python dictionary
store_details = [
        ["name"],
        ["city"]
    ]

# Learn how to loop better =/
for stores in [item["store_details"] for item in json_array]
```

Here's the sample JSON Data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1000,
    "type": "BigBox",
    "name": "Mall of America",
    "address": "340 W Market",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Bloomington",
    "state": "MN",
    "zip": "55425",
    "location": {
      "lat": 44.85466,
      "lon": -93.24565
    },
    "hours": "Mon: 10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7",
    "services": [
      "Geek Squad Services",
      "Best Buy Mobile",
      "Best Buy For Business"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1002,
    "type": "BigBox",
    "name": "Tempe Marketplace",
    "address": "1900 E Rio Salado Pkwy",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Tempe",
    "state": "AZ",
    "zip": "85281",
    "location": {
      "lat": 33.430729,
      "lon": -111.89966
    },
    "hours": "Mon: 10-9; Tue: 10-9; Wed: 10-9; Thurs: 10-9; Fri: 10-10; Sat: 10-10; Sun: 10-8",
    "services": [
      "Windows Store",
      "Geek Squad Services",
      "Best Buy Mobile",
      "Best Buy For Business"
    ]}
  ]
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your `for` loop statement, Each `item` in `json_array` is a dictionary and the dictionary does not have a key `store_details`. So I modified the program a little bit

```
import json

input_file = open ('stores-small.json')
json_array = json.load(input_file)
store_list = []

for item in json_array:
    store_details = {"name":None, "city":None}
    store_details['name'] = item['name']
    store_details['city'] = item['city']
    store_list.append(store_details)

print(store_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived at this question simply looking for a way to read a json file into memory, then use the built-in `json` module.

```py
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

If you have a json string in memory that needs to be parsed, use `json.loads()` instead:

```py
data = json.loads(my_json_string)
```

Either way, now `data` is converted into a Python data structure (list/dictionary) that may be (deeply) nested and you'll need Python methods to manipulate it.

---

If you arrived here looking for ways to get values under several keys as in the OP, then the question is about looping over a Python data structure. For a not-so-deeply-nested data structure, the most readable (and possibly the fastest) way is a list / dict comprehension. For example, for the requirement in the OP, a list comprehension does the job.

```py
store_list = [{'name': item['name'], 'city': item['city']} for item in json_array]
# [{'name': 'Mall of America', 'city': 'Bloomington'}, {'name': 'Tempe Marketplace', 'city': 'Tempe'}]
```

Other types of common data manipulation:

1. For a nested list where each sub-list is a list of items in the `json_array`.

   ```py
   store_list = [[item['name'], item['city']] for item in json_array]
   # [['Mall of America', 'Bloomington'], ['Tempe Marketplace', 'Tempe']]
   ```
2. For a dictionary of lists where each key-value pair is a category-values in the `json_array`.

   ```py
   store_data = {'name': [], 'city': []}
   for item in json_array:
       store_data['name'].append(item['name'])
       store_data['city'].append(item['city'])
   # {'name': ['Mall of America', 'Tempe Marketplace'], 'city': ['Bloomington', 'Tempe']}
   ```
3. For a "transposed" nested list where each sub-list is a "category" in `json_array`.

   ```py
   store_list = list(store_data.values())
   # [['Mall of America', 'Tempe Marketplace'], ['Bloomington', 'Tempe']]
   ```