# How to read a file containing two contiguous dictionaries as JSON?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have JSON files, which contains two dictionaries, which are not separated by any delimiter. I need to get each of those dictionaries as individual JSON objects. How can I go about doing this? I am working in Python.

The files looks like

```
{"data":[[], [], ...., []]}{"data":[[], [], ..., []]}
```

The file could contains like 10K inner arrays.

I tried reading the file in line format, as I saw in a few solutions here and there but none of them are working.

```
data = json.load(f)
```

gives me the error

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 115451 (char 115450)

I also tried

```
data = []
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

but it gives me the same error,

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 115451 (char 115450)

Comment: please post the json

Comment: Can't share the exact file, bounded by some conditions, have added the outline of the json

Comment: [this might be a different possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060035/python-parse-json-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060035/python-parse-json-array)

Comment: That won't work because the dictionaries in that json are inside a list, so can be read as list elements, which is not in my case

Comment: does the data contain `{` or `}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve JSON objects from a text file using Python where the objects are \*not\* separated by a delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730119/how-to-retrieve-json-objects-from-a-text-file-using-python-where-the-objects-are)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try reading the file as text first and then parse it, but the data may not contain `{` or `}`:

```py
import re

text = "{abc}{cd:'ef'}" # change this(might have to remove newlines)

print(re.findall('{.*}', text))
```

|
|
↓

```py
[{abc},{cd:"ef"}]
```